# Format text in Photoshop CS6+ via Javascript

Tags: javascript, photoshop

Is it possible to format a text layer in Photoshop with JavaScript?  For example, I would like to format the following text layer...

```
4/16/2013
```

...to look like this...

```
April 16, 2013
```

Is this possible?  If so, how do we apply from start to finish?

Thanks

Comment: thanks Renan for the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes possible using [**Photoshop scripting**](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html). [**Here**](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/07/25/introduction-to-photoshop-scripting/) is good start.

For more information, check this [**pdf**](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/photoshop/pdfs/cs6/Photoshop-CS6-JavaScript-Ref.pdf)